# How is Cas9-gRNA-tracrRNA complex lysed in mammalian cells?

Tags: genetics, biochemistry

I am interested in degradation of Cas9-gRNA-tracrRNA complex. I would like to understand how do the cas9 enzyme, gRNA and tracrRNA degrade in mammalian cells (with references, if possible).

Answer (score 3):

There has not been much research on *this* part of CRISPR-Cas system, as everybody is interested in geting gene editing done, but very few think about what *actually* happens to the things we leave inside. So, the mechanism of its degradation is not well understood. But there has been *some* research on this, which leads to the conclusion that the Cas9-gRNA, being a ribonucleoprotein (RNP), degrades by the normal protein degradation pathways, and is indeed very quick process. See [this](http://blog.addgene.org/genome-engineering-using-cas9/grna-ribonucleoproteins-rnps) article:

> By contrast, Cas9 RNPs are delivered as intact complexes, are detectable at high levels shortly after transfection, and are quickly cleared from the cell via protein degradation pathways...Second, rapid clearance of Cas9 RNPs from the cell may increase CRISPR specificity by reducing the amount of time that Cas9 is available for off-target cleavage...Cas9 RNPs are active immediately following transfection and are quickly degraded within the cell. These fast degradation kinetics enable Cas9 RNPs to modify target genes with reduced off-target effects.

For more information about RNP degradation, you can have a look at [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4371321/) article. An example of RNP degradation pathway is [this](http://www.cell.com/trends/molecular-medicine/fulltext/S1471-4914(16)30039-9) too:

[image: RNP degradation]